# resizeBy throwing "Access is denied" exception in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am trying to resize the window in IE. For this, I am using

```
window.resizeBy(width - document.documentElement.clientWidth, height - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
```

However, sometimes this fails with an "Access is denied" exception. The way I was handling this was just to use

```
setTimeout('resizeWindow(' + width + ', ' + height + ')', 200);
```

if the exception occurs to try again a little later.

The trouble is it is now causing a race condition if the window needs to be re-sized several times in quick succession.

Does anyone know why the "Access is denied" exception might be being thrown and how to avoid it?

Comment: *"the window needs to be re-sized several times in quick succession"* - o_O Why would something like that be necessary? For my part, I would get incredibly annoyed if a web app I use did this...

Comment: @Tomalak I would get incredibly annoyed if a web app resized my browser even once...

Comment: @Rowland: If there was a popup window for some reason, I would accept one-time resizing to proper dimensions. (If popup windows are good or necessary is another discussion.) All other cases would annoy me instantly as well.

Comment: It is a popup window that resizes in response to a user action to toggle a sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resize happens in response to the user clicking on a button. On mousedown on the button an event is triggered, which in turn resizes the window. If the user held the button down during the resize IE throws the exception as it does not allow windows to resize while the button is down (presumably for usability reasons). Rapidly toggling the button increased the likelihood that the mouse button would be down while it tried to resize the window.